# In Alfresco Share, how to refer to a nodeRef id in the custom config file?

Tags: share, alfresco, document-library

I'm trying to extend Share DocumentLibrary with a new action that provide a link to some url based on the nodeRef Id (through **share-config-custom.xml**)

```
 <action id="blabla" type="link" label="label">
         <param name="page">../../alfresco/wcs/myPlugin/editor/{node.nodeRef.id}/param>
        <param name="target">_blank</param>
 </action>
```

But Share does not interpret `{node.nodeRef.id}`

It does interpret `{node.nodeRef}` correctly but I don't need the full URI

Like: `workspace://SpacesStore/158f0ed4-a575-40c2-a6ef-7e7ed386ba94` 
I just want the node ref id : `158f0ed4-a575-40c2-a6ef-7e7ed386ba94`

Anyone can explain me the logic behind this and suggest a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I assume you are asking for Alfresco 4.0. The way how actions can be extended is completely new in 4.0 and most of us haven't used that yet.

The logic that creates the place holders is probably in Java code in the Share webapp (haven't found the exact location). The node.nodeRef is a String so you can not call nodeRef.id. In my opinion you have two options:

- You can keep **type="link"** and node.nodeRef but you link to a custom repository side webscript which then generates the correct URL and forwards (HTTP Status 301) to the correct destination.
- You change the type to **type="javascript"** and implement a callback function in Javascript. This will be called when the link is clicked and can build the correct Url. To include custom javascript you can use the *dependencies* in the Share config:

As far as I know the only documentation available for extending the new actions is:

- http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/mikeh/tag/4-0/
- http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/doclib-web-tier.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use node.id as seen at the Javascript API [Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.4_JavaScript_API#ScriptNode_API)

Comment: I've tried it already it doesn't work. This is a config file not javascript

Comment: But you've defined a custom action right? You can there pick the NodeRef and convert it to Node and do node.id. So post you action where you do have the Freemarker Language and or Javascript available

Comment: in Freemarker how do you convert the NodeRef to a Node in the Share webapp? cause it doesn't recognise companyhome for example

Comment: In Freemarker there is no utillity to convert a String to Node. In Javascript there is: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.4_JavaScript_API#Utility_Functions . So you can first get the node from Javascript and then pass it on through the Model to Freemarker.You can preferably post all your files, so I/We can take a look at it.